# jQuery Sortable List Not Reordering on create

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to re-order the elements of a list in a jquery sortable when it is created based on which order they are in in a list.

```
var CACHES = ["WayBack Machine", "Google Cache", "Coral CDN"];
var HTML = ["Google Cache", "WayBack Machine", "Coral CDN"];

$("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        // When the item postion is changed while dragging a item, I want it's position
        console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("Sortable Created");

        var ul = $('#sortable');
        var li = ul.children('li').get();

        li.sort(function(a,b) {
            $(a).attr('id')
            var value = CACHES.indexOf($(a).attr('id')) < CACHES.indexOf($(b).attr('id')) ? 1 : -1
            console.log(value)
            return value
        });

        ul.append(li);
    }
});
```

var HTML is the order that they are in in the HTML of the page. var CACHES is the order that I want to put them in. It does seem to reorder the elements, but not correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

use - instead of < and ternary

```
var value = CACHES.indexOf($(a).attr('id')) - CACHES.indexOf($(b).attr('id'));
```